# Why wont bash script run by Maven SCP my file?

Tags: bash, maven, jenkins, cygwin, ssh-keys

I have a bash script, amongst other things, attempts to SCP a file from current host (Windows/Cygwin) to a remote host (Suse).

When I run the script in Cygwin myself, the script performs perfectly. Transfers the file via SCP, then SSH to the remote machine to run some further commands (to do with deploying the file to application server).

When the script is run by Maven as part of a Jenkins CI build it fails with an error about the key pair being rejected.

From the Jenkins job log:

```
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Comment: It is because jenkins process is being run as a different unix user who may not have same keys stored in `~/.ssh` directory.

Comment: I pass the key file with the ssh -i flag, the user thing is plausible if the maven/jenkins user can't read that file for some reason.

Is there a way I can launch cygwin as a windows user that would have full access across the system?

Or maybe make the key available to all users in cygwin somehow?

Comment: Ah `cygwin` Sorry don't know that very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your job run once with StrictHostKeyChecking:

```
scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' ...
```

This will log something like:

```
Warning: Permanently added '<host>, <ipaddr>' (<keytype>) to the list of known hosts.
```

After that, remove the StrictHostKeyChecking.

Comment: sborsky - you have just made my week!